# Android font family not working in api <=~21?

Tags: android, android-layout, fonts, font-awesome, android-resources

I am using FontAwesome 5 ttf files, so I have made a font family like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<font-family xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <font 
        app:font="@font/font_awesome_5_pro_regular_400"
        app:fontStyle="normal"
        app:fontWeight="400"
        />
    <font
        app:font="@font/font_awesome_5_pro_solid_900"
        app:fontStyle="normal"
        app:fontWeight="900"
        />
    <font
        app:font="@font/font_awesome_5_pro_light_300"
        app:fontStyle="italic"
        app:fontWeight="300"
        />
</font-family>
```

So that I can define string resources like so:

```
<string name="fa_gift_light"><i>\uf06b</i></string>
<string name="fa_gift_bold"><b>\uf06b</b></string>
```

And get heavy, light, and normal versions of an icon. This works fine in API's above ~21 (I haven't actually checked at what version it breaks, but I know it doesn't work in APIs 19 and 21 and my project's minimum is 19), but in APIs below that the "italic" style just slants the normal version of the icon like so:

[slanted icon (should be light)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SEE4h.png)

Any ways to fix this besides completely abandoning the font family approach?

Answer (score 0):

you can check calligraphy library , a good library for font customisation
you can check it from Gihub 
url :-https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy